# Statistics of Facebook App permissions acceptance differences

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

Has anyone been able to find any statistics OR is there a page/report provided by Facebook that sheds more light on the difference in app acceptance based on which permissions you ask a user to accept?

Obviously I'm guessing that asking them for the "email" extended permissions would turn more users away, but what about "publish_stream" vs. only the base permissions.

I've been looking online but it seems there are no real stats published anywhere.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how "attractive" your app obviously.

if we take Asking authorization make 100 points of bouncing
Asking more authorization like email  50 points
publish_stream                        50 points

so by asking extended authorization you double your bounce rate.
however publish_stream you could have done with FB.ui

numbers are my guess&experience from my apps